# untar tarball with non unique file names

Tags: tar

I have a .tar file I need to extract that looks like this

```
tar tvf bla
100   part1/part1
336   part1/part1
754   part1/part1
638   part1/part1
```

The folder and filenames all have the same name, even though the files themselves are unique.
When I extract the tar file, "part1" is overwritten multiple times and I am left with only the last "part1".  How can I extract these files and give them distinct names? I really don't care what the names are, I just need them to be distinct so when I extract them none of them are overwritten.

One possible output could be

```
part1/part1.1
      part1.2
      part1.3
      part1.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a Python solution that works

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open([SOMEFILE])
offset = 1
for tarinfo in tar:
   tarinfo.name = "parts1." + str(offset)
   tar.extract(tarinfo, path="parts1")
   offset +=1
```

This produces

```
  parts1/parts1.1
        parts1.2
        parts1.3
        parts1.4
```